# What´s the best approach to share info between all the pages of a React made website?

Tags: reactjs

I have my site complete (on localhost) with its api, database, login... everything works fine, but I need to improve one thing, let me explain.

As I´m new to React (and even to backend stuff) I´m pretty sure there are several ways to make this better. When an user logs into the site, I save on local store a jwt token with a timestamp and then I can check it on every single page so that way if the user logged in more than X minutes ago (stored in a env variable) I delete both localStorage items and redirect to the login page again.

As I said, everything works like a charm but that token is there, stored in the localStorage and I want to know better ways to do this. I don´t know if React Context is an option here, or any other better way?

Comment: Context, Redux, Reducers, Local Storage, Cookies are your options. Which you prefer is up to your personal pereference

Comment: @mousetail I´m quite happy with the end result using localStorage, but I guess another options, probably Context and Redux should be better as that info is not stored phisically (even yes, you can access to it).